# .htaccess 301 redirect; exclude directory and get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following in .htacces to make a 301 domain redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exa-mple.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exa-mple.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I want to exclude URLs that contain directory `/test/` or get parameter `?test=`/`&test=`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude them like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING) !(?:^|&)test= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?exa-mple\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^test/ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the directory and get perameters , add the follow condition  right above your rewriterule

```
 #exclude /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
#exclude urls that contain test query key ?test
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/\?test [NC]
```